# Could you help me understand the meaning of "for" in "arrival for 30 cities"?

Tags: grammar

"arrival for 30 cities"

I saw this words in the advertisement on CNN .
It was from travel company.

Comment: I think this question does not provide enough information. Could you update the question with some more information about context and such?

Comment: I want to do that.But I cannot remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are saying they can offer you ways of getting to 30 different cities ("***arrivals***").
They are probably either new routes for the company or very exotic and in-demand cities.

Comment: thanks, I thought <they offer for the sake of 30 cities.>

Comment: but after i hear your thought, I think your opinion is right

Comment: so, if it was not exotic or new, then they should use the preposions of <in> or <at> , but they use <for>

Comment: usually Enlglish users don't use <for> , when they say <arrive>

Comment: Keep in mind it is an advertisement and meant to attract your attention.